# Symfony form CollectionType remove empty value

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm using Symfony 3.3 and I have a form with a CollectionType like :

```
$builder->add('links', CollectionType::class, array(
    'label' => false,
    'entry_type' => LinkType::class,
    'entry_options' => ['data_class' => CompanyLink::class],
    'allow_add' => true,
    'allow_delete' => true,
    'prototype' => true,
    'by_reference' => false,
));
```

I followed the documentation : https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

This is what I have in my view :

[image]

So, the form displays well data already in my database (one line each time) but it always adds an empty field in addition.

How can I remove this empty field? Because I want to have this line only I click on the button "Ajouter".

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are not adding an empty entry somewhere (in your controller for instance) ?

Comment: Hello, Yes I am

Comment: Have you tried with `delete_empty` option? https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html#delete-empty

Comment: Yes, for me delete empty is when you submit your form

Comment: Oh right, now I understand your question. Can you show us a `{{ dump() }}` for the underlying object to this form?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Did you find a solution for this problem? Currently running into the same issue myself

Comment: @TristanGodfrey : nop sorry

Answer (score 1):

I think in your function of rendering form you have setData(),

to render the form without data, you just need to do this sample:

```
//Your main entity
$mainEntity = new Entity();
//adding the other entity into collection variable of other entity of main entity
$mainEntity->addOtherEntity(new otherEntity());

$form = $this->createForm(
        MainEntityForm::class,
        $mainEntity
);
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This post is a bit old ihope it's not to late. I found a solution, even if you travel the collectionType field with a twig for.
To avoid having this empty field after your for loop, add

```
{% do form.your_field.setRendered %}
```

It worked for me, hope it will do the same for you :)